# Using Templates with Custom Post Type UI

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I'm using this nifty little plugin called [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to add custom post types to my WordPress site and am having a little trouble working out the best way to apply a page template to my custom post types.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WordPress has a built-in [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) that determines what template file will be loaded for a given type of post or page.  If you have a look at the [visual overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview) of the hierarchy, you'll find that custom posts have their own specific entries.  For example, if your custom post type is named `book`, then a single post's template will be `single-book.php` if it exists, `single.php` if it does not.  (`index.php` is the global fallback -- a theme really only *needs* to contain `style.css` and `index.php` to function.)

Any desired template files (ie, `single-{$posttype}.php`)  should be added to your active theme.

#### References

- [Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)
- [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: Ok, so let's take your example. Let's say we have a custom post type called "book". A file called single-book.php controls is my template for any singular "book" pages while archive-book.php is my template for the archive of my custom post type "book"? This works for "single-book.php", I can edit this template fine. But for some reason, it doesn't work for "archive-book.php". Any reason why?

Comment: @realph are you sure that the CPT is registered with `has_archive` set to `true`?

Comment: @G.M.You are the best! Thanks for that, should do a bit more searching next time. Working perfectly now!

Comment: Sorry, one last question: So is using the template hierarchy the correct way to go about setting up templates for your custom post types?

Comment: The template hierarchy is essentially a flowchart that tells you what files WordPress will try to use to display a given post/page/archive/taxonomy/etc.  It will use the left-most file that it finds. If all else fails it will use `index.php`.

Comment: @PatJ `single-myname_posttype.php` seems to be the simplest answer
I tried creating a `single-posttype.php` file and it didn't work... I finally fell on the the page `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=cptui_listings#post-types` that indicates (for post type name artwork) :
 
```
Archives file name examples.
archive-artwork_posttype.php
archive.php
index.php

Single Posts file name examples.
single-artwork_posttype-post_slug.php *
single-artwork_posttype.php
single.php
singular.php
index.php ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question about the CPT UI. (~10y later now, so I thought I'd post what I found) Specifically, where in CPT UI do I find the template structure I should use to customize my front-end cpt display?

I found if you visit the "Registered Types/Taxonomies" in the CPT UI there is a column for Template Hierarchy.

this would be the URL:
wp-admin/admin.php?page=cptui_listings#post-types